# Error: Object not found while running the code in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

I am very new to R and have just started writing smalls functions. here I have written a function that takes data frame as its argument and returns the mean of each column

Code :

```
n = c(12,13,14,16,16)
m = c(11,2,23,45,67)
a = c(34,343,5,2,1)
b = c(88,33,2,1,44)

db = data.frame (n,m,a,b )

db
   n  m   a  b
1 12 11  34 88
2 13  2 343 33
3 14 23   5  2
4 16 45   2  1
5 16 67   1 44

mean.dataframe = function (df)
{
    for (i in 1:ncol(df))
    {
        j[i]= mean(df[[i]])
    }

    print (j)
}


avgcol = mean.dataframe(db)
```

> Error in j[i] = mean(df[[i]]) : object 'j' not found

I dont understand the  error.  When I run this in Rstudio it gives this error. However, in R it does not.

Comment: You may also have a look at `colMeans`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code doesn't work, independently of RStudio. When you type `j[i]` then R considers the `i`-th element of `j`, but `j` is not defined. Define it before:

```
mean.dataframe = function (df)
{
    j = rep(NA,ncol(df))
    for (i in 1:ncol(df))
    {
        j[i]= mean(df[[i]])
    }

    print (j)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use colMeans?

```
colMeans (x)
```

Comment: Indeed, but the question is : *why this code doesn't work ?*.

Comment: @StéphaneLauren, `colMeans` doesn't answer the question. It's a different solution, which was already offered in comments

Comment: @DavidArenburg This is not important, but the main point of the question is not : *how to calculate the columns means?*, but is : *why this code doesn't work*. So this doesn't answer at all to the question. I'm just doing this remark because I have already experimented such answers to some of my questions.